# How to add new packages in Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes

As the title, I added a new algorithm package in the `plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/priorities` folder for Kubernetes. It is a folder, there are some Go source files, like the `util` folder. But, when run `make`, I got the errors:

```
test/e2e_node/e2e_node.test
    cmd/gke-certificates-controller
plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/priorities/test.go:7:2: no buildable Go source files in /home/zhangjian/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/priorities/test
!!! [0703 09:22:46] Call tree:
!!! [0703 09:22:46]  1: /home/zhangjian/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:740 kube::golang::build_binaries_for_platform(...)
!!! [0703 09:22:46]  2: hack/make-rules/build.sh:27 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
!!! [0703 09:22:46] Call tree:
!!! [0703 09:22:46]  1: hack/make-rules/build.sh:27 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
!!! [0703 09:22:46] Call tree:
!!! [0703 09:22:46]  1: hack/make-rules/build.sh:27 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

They are the Go files indeed, I didn't know the reason of the error. Or something else I missed?

And I just want to add my own algorithm package (not the third libs, such `exapmle.com/xxx/xxx`) into the `priority`, so what's the steps?

I referred to [community/contributors/devel/godep.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/godep.md) and tried `go build ./...`, `./hack/godep-restore.sh`, `./hack/godep-save.sh` commands, but still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be caused by `CGO_ENABLED` variable, still need to set it enable in `hack/lib/golang.sh` file (a file of kubernetes project) although you enabled it in environment variable.